# Run a script when pi is pinged

Tags: networking, ping

I want my pi to beep when I ping it.  I already have a script that makes it beep.  How can I run the script when the pi is pinged?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a Raspberry Pi issue, however since the Pi runs Linux you can use `tcpdump` to filter for all ICMP packets and then use `grep` to search for just the requests and then `xargs` to run an `echo` command to output the `bel` character for each ICMP Echo request.

The following command worked for me (I had to configure Putty to not limit the number of alerts in a row):

```
sudo tcpdump -l -i eth0 icmp 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered request | xargs -n1 echo -ne '\007'
```

You may need to `sudo apt-get install tcpdump` to install `tcpdump`.

Beware that this command will generate the `bel` alert for every ICMP echo request.  Other machines on your network can also be sending echo requests to your machine.  You may need to filter for the IP address of a specific machine if you only want certain pings to trigger this.

Some notes, the `-l` option is needed for `tcpdump` to force `tcpdump` to not buffer output.
`--line-buffered` is needed for `grep` for the same purpose.

Comment: I am not clear how this runs a script.  When you say "bel character" are you talking about a system beep that might come out or the hdmi or something?  Because I am just using a piezo buzzer that it attached to a gpio pin.  The command I tried was ```sudo tcpdump -l -i eth0 icmp 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered request | sudo bash beep.sh ``` but that just beeps once then exits.

Comment: The command you listed should beep once for each ping.  I thought that was what you wanted.  If not, please update your question with more details.